# Prevent authors from seeing other authors media files in media upload dialog in Wordpress 3.5 and with ACF

Tags: php, plugins, custom-fields, media-library, wordpress-3.5

I've been struggling with this problem for a good while now, and just can't seem to get it work.

I have

- a multiuser wordpress 3.5 site with [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://advancedcustomfields.com/).
- a custom post type, gallery, in which authors can post their photos through custom fields
- a custom field in user profile.

When an author is uploading a photo into a post, the author can see other authors' uploads in the media upload dialog. I don't want this to happen. I want authors to see only their own uploads in the media upload dialog.

I can get this to work, with this:

```
// Prevent Authors from seeing other authors media files 
add_filter('parse_query', 'my_parse_query' );
function my_parse_query( $wp_query ) {
// Only applicable for Media Library && Media Upload Dialog
if (! preg_match('/wp-admin\/(?:upload|media-upload|admin-ajax).php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
   return;
}
global $current_user;
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
if ($user_role && is_string($user_role) && strtolower($user_role)==='author') {
  $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->id );
}
}
```

But in turn, this prevents the custom fields from working in the user profiles. This is because ACF uses the admin-ajax to add the fields to an edit screen, but if I remove the admin-ajax part from the function above, it starts to show other authors media again, so it's back to square one.

I've tried to use dozens of different methods [(1)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78084/prevent-other-editors-from-viewing-images-of-other-editors-in-add-media-popup)[(2)](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/view-own-posts-media-only)[(3)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded) that I've found from the internet, but none of them work due to the new wordpress 3.5 media upload dialog and/or ACF.

Any idea how to prevent authors from seeing other authors media, while using ACF?

Comment: I found the following solution, take a look:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded I used the code provided in the second best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
if($wp_query->query_vars['post_type']!=='attachment'){return;}
```

It will work.
Regards.